# Print header and footer on each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, browser

I have a text editor and i want to take the content of the editor and open a new window then I put header and footer and the content in the middle.
If there is no content it should also show the footer on the bottom.
Also I want the header and footer to be printed on each single page.

How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: Use the position:fixed for the elements and they will be displayed on each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use javascript. Use PHP. You can call the header and the footer files directly or as an action and then you can tell the server to not serve the footer or header on certain 'pages' or 'rules'.

```
<?php
include 'filename';

**or**

require 'filename';
?>
```

You can use the if statement to declare a rule on when the footer should or should not be displayed: `http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php`